# Website won't fully load without fragment identifier in URL

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my first time posting here and I probably won't give u much info to work with, but I'll try. I've tested my website locally and it works perfectly. I uploaded it to the server and it doesn't fully work without "#" in URL (it doesn't load background picture, only background color).

I cant find problem in code so its impossible to copy-paste 100 000 lines of code here, but I can give u working and nonworking link

Here is the link of the website: arminmuzaferija.ba
arminmuzaferija.ba/# (working one)

**NOTE:** All website links are set as "#" because its still under construction.A

Comment: a point to start would be to clean up HTML-[errors](https://validator.nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Farminmuzaferija.ba%2F)

Comment: There are no errors at all. Nothing is pops out in inspect element console.

Comment: checkout my HTML-errors link, or look at right-mouse-button `show source` of your page. Starting at line 171 you get RED marked html which is how the browser tells you that this is invalid markup.

Comment: I cleaned it but no change. The thing that is bugging me the most is that webpage works perfect locally..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug was in the path for pictures used in slider (which was not loading without fragment identifier in URL). JavaScript expected full path.

**WRONG:** `<img src="images/picture.png">`

**RIGHT:** `<img src="http://arminmuzaferija.ba/images/picture.png">`